# WordPress new comment xmlrpc.php

Tags: wordpress, api, comments, xml-rpc

I've got a problem: I need to post new comment using xmlrpc.php and POST request.

I read documentation and wrote a XML request. Then I sent it to blog/xmlrpc.php, but there is a problem: faultCode -32700 parse error. not well formed.I tried to find a solution, but other XML do not work too.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>wp.newComment</methodName>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <int>1</int>
            </value>
        </param>
        <param>
            <value>
                <string>GrinJ</string>
            </value>
        </param>
        <param>
            <value>
                <string>0</string>
            </value>
        </param>
        <param>
            <value>
                <int>1406</int>
            </value>
        </param>
        <param>
            <value>
                <struct>
                    <member>
                        <name>comment_parent</name>
                        <value>
                            <int>0</int>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>content</name>
                        <value>
                            <string>Test</string>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>author</name>
                        <value>
                            <string>GrinJ</string>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>author_url</name>
                        <value>
                            <string>http://example.org</string>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>author_email</name>
                        <value>
                            <string>test@example.com</string>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                </struct>
            </value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>
```

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?